# windows 7 domain roaming profiles - can i set it up so that only differences are synced with local copy?

Tags: windows, roaming-profile, synchronization, dfs-r

I have read answers regarding roaming profiles that recommend using folder redirection (like [Profile Roaming, to make not to copy all the files to the local PC](https://serverfault.com/questions/317123/profile-roaming-to-make-not-to-copy-all-the-files-to-the-local-pc?rq=1)).

I don't want the profile dirs to be stored on the network and deleted from local each time because i want them to be able to work when there is a server problem too...

But assuming I want an updated copy of the profile (Desktop and My documents) backed up on the domain and also don't want each login/logoff operation to copy *all* the profile files back and forth(a waste of time)... what is my solution to just sync the differences ?

I also saw this question:
[Moving roaming profiles to DFS](https://serverfault.com/questions/264821/moving-roaming-profiles-to-dfs)

Maybe the solution is creating for each user a DFS-R solution between their local profile copy and the central domain one ?

Comment: Even if this were possible, it would be an administrative nightmare, methinks. I think you misunderstand DFS, since it is a server technology for replication between servers. As @MartinBinder mentions, your solution is in Group Policy, not DFS.

Answer (score 0):

Profile sync only copies differences, so there's no need to use local profiles only. In addition, if a local copy already exists the user is still able to logon when the server copy is unreachable.
The local copy is never deleted unless you explicitly specify to do so (http://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net/#2570 and http://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net/#2583 are the two GPO settings to delete local copies of roaming profiles, either immediately or after a given time not being used)

Comment: A word of warning... I was downvoted the other day for not including the relevant parts from a link. It might be better to include the GPO settings rather than just linking to a similar article.